# Repetition in Sefer Yere'im

Tags: torah-study, mitzvah, rishonim, tosfot

The sefer Yere'im of [R. Eliezer of Metz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eliezer_ben_Samuel) which lists the 613 mitzvos seems to count several identical mitzvos. E.g. [mitzvos 25-30](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=22393&st=&pgnum=169&hilite=) (according to the newer editions). Although I could creatively distinguish between his various descriptions, they seem to overlap. Is there any discussion of this repetition in particular, or of his general approach to counting mitzvos in general?

---

The following is a summary of the mitzvos in question:
25) Studying Torah
26) Teaching Torah
27) Learning Torah constantly
28) Learning Torah constantly
29) Teaching Torah
30) Learning Torah

Comment: I didn't read through your source, but I'm positive there is no distinction between #26 and #29 as well as #27 and #28 in your summary. || Anyway, doesn't every count of Mitzvos have some multiples for the same act?

Comment: @Yishai Indeed. the apparent repetition was the point under discussion. "Anyway, doesn't every count of Mitzvos have some multiples for the same act" Perhaps. That was the primary question-the Yereiims approach to counting mitzvos.